# Android :: need to perform some tasks when android application resumes not activity

Tags: android

In my android app, sqlite db gets installed when first time app is installed.i have kept sqlite db on amazon aws server. app downloads the 
db from there.

Now when user opens the app, it should check if there is new db on server. if it is there then download otherwise use existing db.

My question is where and when should i do the above db check in android app? I want to do this when application resumes not particular activity.

I was thiking to do it in Onresume() of the main activity, but i think it may be called or not called if user closes the app when he is in different activity. I have to consider performance also...

let's say we have activities A, B, and C. They can jump back and forth between one another. Every time one of those are invoked, OnResume() always get's fired. And the user could potentially leave the application on activity B or C, do some browsing, and come back to the app on activity B or C.

Please help....

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the

```
onCreate
```

method of you Application class.
[Here the link to Application class reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)

Answer (score 0):

I found some questions about your understanding Sqlite. **SQLite is in-built but not "installed when first time app is installed".** **The db you using is created the first time when you use it.** And then it will always exist there. You can update it when something wrong happened to this db.
Meantime, you can use the life span methods of Activity with some little private boolean parameters. For example, boolean flag=false in A, when you skip to B, onPause of A will be called, then you can set flag=true. And then you return to A, onResume will be called, then you can do something like this:

```
if(flag){
  //check your db status
    flag=false;
} else {
  //do something else here.
}
```

Comment: By saying "sqlite db gets installed when first time app is installed" i meant the same. I have created databse in sqlite. and this db is installed when first time app is installed.  As you are saying maintain flag in the activity...it seems very complicated. i dint want to check db status every time when user comes or goes from activity. it wont be good as per the performence.